# Next.js is exposing my environment variables to the client

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am having an issue with my project where an environment variable is getting exposed to the browser. According to [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser), only environment variables prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` should be accessible in the browser environment, but in my case, all environment variables are getting exposed.

Here is an example:
.env.local:

```
SECRET=SECRET_VALUE
```

/app/page.tsx

```
export default function Home(){
  return (
    <div>{process.env.SECRET}</div>
  )
}
```

The above code shows the value "SECRET_VALUE" in the browser.
[Here](https://github.com/AhmedAlSaey/nextjs-exposed-env) is a simple code example to replicate the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this rule is for recent versions of nextjs, what version are you using now?

Comment: Are you sure the environment variable is exposed directly to the client and not just rendered to HTML server-side?

Comment: @Mechanic I am using next version v13.4.19 according to `npx next --version`

Comment: @Quentin Can you clarify the difference and how do I test for that in Next.js? If you could also take a look at my example on GitHub, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing `process.env.secret` is that your page is being rendered on the server by default. And environment variables are accessible via server.

This means that when the server wants to render your page, it has access to the env variable and it reads the value and the way you're adding it to the DOM, it will eventually show the value of it.

In order to not expose your env variable to the client, you can simply add `use client` to top of the `/app/page.tsx` to mark the page as part of client bundle which gets rendered by React on the client. However, this will cause the hydration error which is out of scope your question but you can read more [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) if you want.

In order to have fully functional demo without the hydration error I mentioned above, you can use the code below and check the `console.log` values in the terminal you're running the Next app and compare it with the value you get from the browser:

```
'use client';

export default function Home() {
  console.log('env variable is: ', process.env.SECRET);

  return <div>Compare console log values in app terminal and browser</div>;
}
```